# Why Vaadin stops starting while compiling the frontend?

Tags: spring, vaadin

My Vaadin+Spring Boot App suddenly stops starting locally. I already purged IntelliJ Caches, rebuilt the project and made a mvn clean. Does anyone can help me find the issue? At the following point the log stops logging, but wont finishing frontend compiling. the App is also not reachable in the browser at this point

```
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
2021-12-21 21:07:47.371  INFO 4376 --- [onPool-worker-3] dev-webpack                              : Running webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2021-12-21 21:07:49.753  INFO 4376 --- [onPool-worker-3] dev-webpack                              : Started webpack-dev-server. Time: 2383ms
```

Comment: Did you remove node_modules directory? Also which Vaadin version are you using? and did your app stop working after some change (say, a version upgrade)?

Comment: Clean is not enough also do mvn vaadin:dance this will remove the generated files

Answer (score 0):

I knwo this thread is old, but I resolved the same error.
The error came from NodeJs. If your using Vaadin 14.2 or higher you should uninstall your current NodeJs Version and reinstall it through running the run-command
urr-app[spring-boot:run]
Now everything should work. Or you use a versioning system.